# SWFUpload uppload error 500 - asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, upload, file-upload, swfupload

I have a asp.net website where I am using the Flash SWFUpload (http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/) upload component.

The same code is hosted on two servers - on server A I can upload images without any problems.
On server B I get Error 500 when I try to upload - no other error message.

I am unable to find what server settings are different between those two servers.
I cant find any solution on SWFUpload forum.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similiar problem using an apache httpd server
fixed it using an answer from [SWFUpload forum](http://swfupload.org/forum/generaldiscussion/86).

hope it will help.

short version:
append

```
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
```

to .htaccess in root.

Also I want to comment that this is **less secure**.

Comment: Ok, Than I Suggest Using A Similar Option In Web.config I Personally Don't Use IIS, But I Think Your Solution Will Be Located at Http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssa0wsyf.aspx